# Google Add-On for Sheets launches on refresh

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I am currently in the process of releasing and publishing an Add-On for Google Sheets. Upon Google's review of the add-on, they indicated that the add-on would auto-launch whenever the sheets is refreshed.

How can I change my code so it passes Google review?

EDIT:

```
    function onOpen() {

    var DocObject = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
    //paid = "true" if bought. paid = "false" if not bought. These 
    //are strings not bool values
    var paid = DocObject.Bought;

    if(paid) 
    {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('aPLM')
       .addItem('Open Menu', 'showMenu')
       .addToUi();
    } else 
    {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('aPLM')
        .addItem('Start Registration', 'noTrial')
        .addItem('Open Menu', 'showMenu')
        .addToUi();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably you have code in a function with an "on open" trigger that does more than configure the add-on for use via menu.

Comment: Partly because of security concerns, Google does not want add-ons to automatically open a sidebar or dialog box when the document is opened.  Another reason might be that the user doesn't want to see or use your add-on every time the spreadsheet is opened / refreshed.  People often have multiple add-ons in the same spreadsheet, what would happen if multiple add-ons were all trying to open a sidebar at the same time?  These are some possible reasons why it didn't pass the review.

Comment: You need to use `AuthMode` specific handling in your `onOpen` function.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate you most likely have a function called onOpen(). This will result in you script running whenever the user opens a Google Spreadsheet.

As recommended look at changing your script to run when a menu item is selected. Have a look at the below documentation for adding menus to a spreadsheet.

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus/)

Comment: Hi, I posted my code for my OnOpen() Function on the edit. That code should just run a check to see if the user has bought the add-on or not and then create the menu. 

The whole app should then start when the menu item is clicked.

It does not appear that my onOpen makes the script run but rather just create the menu items for the script to run. Is this not correct?